# what is sudo chown -R www-data:www-data?

Tags: ubuntu

In this above command what is sudo,chown,-R,www-data?
In which place we are using this command,why two times www-data reapeted.
Please explain me.

Comment: You are using this command without knowing why/what it does? Is this a real job?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I'll try to explain is `sudo`.  `sudo` stands for superuser do. Using `sudo`, the user can act as a 'root' level of system operation.  Shortly, `sudo` gives user a privilege as a `root` system.

And then, about `chown`, `chown` is used for setting the ownership of folder or file.  The explanation of `-R` had been answered (it recursively descends to all sub-folders).

So the last thing is about www-data written repeated.`www-data:www-data` the first one is user, the second is group.  Your username can be added as a member of `www-data` group, by this command `sudo adduser user www-data`, user can be replaced with your username.  That command will result in `user www-data`.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for chown is user:group - so this command changes the ownder of all files to www-data, and the group to www-data.

Answer (score 2):

It's recursively changing both the user and group owners for the file path specified.